# Changing getJSON to JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I have this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://example.com/api/get_cats', function(fbResults) {
            document.write(fbResults.cats[0].title);
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I change this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://example.com/api/get_cats', function(fbResults) {
            document.write(fbResults.cats[0].title);
        });
    });
</script>
```

for it to work as JSONP ... Is this totally different?

Comment: Is the data offered from the server as JSONP?

Comment: There's just JSON data on the server

Comment: Then it won't work as a JSONP request. JSONP is basically just a `<script>` request. The response must have the data wrapped in a function call, like `my_func({"foo":"bar"})`. Then when the script arrives, assuming there's a function named `my_func`, that function is invoked passing the data into it. Some servers let you specify the function name, and they'll return the JSONP response, but this behavior must be established on the server.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually, you just have to add `?callback=?`, jQuery does the rest.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/api/get_cats?callback=?', function(fbResults) {
        document.write(fbResults.cats[0].title);
    });
});
```

Comment: I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" because my php is returning json. How do format the php side to call the callback function when it doesn't have a name?

Comment: @curtis I added `output=jsonp&callback=?` as parameters in order to get rid off this error