# How to use the w3c validator API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, w3c

W3C has an API for their html validator (see http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html). But I am confused as to how it is used. I would like to be able to call this as Ajax in jquery and have the information from the validator passed back to me in a variable.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: There's not documentation around a RESTful API, but I you could experiment with the following request format: `http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org` and see what you get back and whether that's digestible.  Otherwise SOAP seems heavily supported.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is a possible update:

In previous answers and comments only a SOAP API was mentioned, which is however, as described [here](https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html), outdated.

A possibility to use the new(?) API is described [here](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service-%C2%BB-Input-%C2%BB-GET):

```
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F&out=json
```

Maybe someone can confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to set up a proxy to do this due the cross-domain restriction.

[How to call SOAP WS from Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796941/how-to-call-soap-ws-from-javascript-jquery)