# nodejs jsonp - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cross-domain

I'm pretty sure JSONP means no cross domain restrictions. I'm trying to make a JSONP service using node and express. Here is simple code:

```
self.routes['/portfolio'] = function(req, res) {
      // Website you wish to allow to connect
         res.jsonp({ "my": "object" });
};
```

When I  do:

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio', function(data){ console.log(data)});
```

I get this error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio. The
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio' that is not equal to the supplied
>   origin. Origin 'http://api.jquery.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Can someone explain what is going on here? Why do we need to supply header value if this is JSONP. How can I make this work cross domain?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916780/changing-getjson-to-jsonp
You need to add callback call also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.getJSON` does not treat the request as JSONP *unless* the request URL includes a string like `callback=?`.

So, try doing this instead;

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio?callback=?', function(data){ console.log(data)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just have to add ?callback=?, jQuery does the rest.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8080/portfolio?callback=?', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Put below code into app.js or server.js

/*************To Allow access to cross domain request *************/

```
   app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
           res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
           res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
           res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
           next();
   });

   /*************To Allow access to cross domain request *************/
```

Comment: He's trying to make a JSONP API, so this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use $.ajax with dataType jsonp

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: 'http://portfoliomanager-sran.rhcloud.com/portfolio?callback=?',
    dataType: 'jsonp'  
}).then(function(response){
console.log(response);
});
```